# Automating powerpoint slides creation with maps for bulk jobs

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, export, qgis-processing, powerpoint

I have about 50 states in US which are subdivided into 200 territories. Often I have to generate powerpoint presentations consisting of map views for all or some territories by going back to each territory and taking a snapshot for each of them. Many a time I need to repeat this task for different layers. This is very time consuming.

Is there any way I could just specify the states and the territories QGIS should generate PowerPoint slides using given layers?